# Android LoginActivity using standard http request

Tags: android, http, authentication

I'm using LoginActivity template and I'm trying to login to a website with email and password using a standard http request. The site doesn't provide an API so I'm thinking of somehow mirroring the site login to fill the email and password boxes on the page then sending the login request.

Think of logging in to stackoverflow for example by taking the input of an email and password TextView (s) and sending a standard http request to the authentication server with those credentials exactly how it would happen in the browser (same requests and addresses).

I haven't done anything like this before and I have no idea if it's even possible so please forgive any ignorance on my part.

Answer (score 1):

This is done in Android in a similar fashion as in the web browser. Namely, you will send a **POST** request with proper parameters, let's say a JSON Object for the sake of explaining which contains something like:

```
{
  username: 'myUsername'
  password: 'mypass'
}
```

This will get processed and if your credentials are correct, you will get a response which may contain a variety of data, among which the `accessToken` (it may be called a slight variation of this).

You are supposed to remember this access token and use it to fetch any other data from the site, because that token is used from there on to authenticate you. I have an API I personally made, and I send the `accessToken` as a parameter in every request for a resource that is unavailable to the unregistered user.

As for the technical side, I'm using a nifty library called [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for sending the Http requests, and it's quite rewarding and easy to use. Here's a code snippet to see what I'm talking about:

```
//JSON is a media type for parsing json
//json is a json string containing payload e.g. username and pass like in the example
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

The only thing left to to for you is to properly parse the `response`. You can find various solutions on this topic, but I personally use 2 approaches, `BufferedReader` for huge responses using `response.body().byteStream()`, and plain old `String` for not-so-large responses using `response.body().string()`.

This is not a short, but very thorough explanation, so feel free to ask for clarification if you do not get some part.

Comment: As I understand it OkHttp in this instance is just a replacement to HttpPost, right? My problem is that I don't have an address to send authentication request to, only a frontend page. The authentication server uses userID hashes which are provided by an SQLite base through the login, so I can't send requests to the server directly only the page with the username and password, after login I can get the hash for my user from the page source but I can't do it before login so I can't send the request. What I need is a way mimic filling the username and password on the page then clicking login.

Comment: Well it is assumed that you do have an account. If you dont, make one. Or if you're asking how to register, thats quite similar, one different url and payload. All in all, comes down to the same thing.

Comment: I'm working off [reddit is fun](https://github.com/talklittle/reddit-is-fun/blob/master/src/com/andrewshu/android/reddit/login/LoginTask.java) login. I understand how it works but the issue is that I don't have an equivalent to REDDIT_LOGIN_URL (https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login) so I have to use the normal login page (https://www.reddit.com/login) so how can I do that?

Comment: Well, in the link you provided people are sending a http request with some kind of body. I do not understand what more you expect from my answer? I really cannot help you further if you do not know what JSON to send in the request to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to log in to sites like StackOverflow from your app with standard http request. That is simply impossible. Because no organizations will allow third party sites/apps handling their users' credentials. If they intend to share their resource with third party most organizations follow this procedure:

- First they provide api for you to use.
- With that api only you can make users to login i.e you can't handle those credentials
- Then they give a token to you corresponding to the user.
- With that token you can perform subsequent requests.

If the organization doesn't provide api then they most probably are in situation of not allowing third party sites/apps to access their users' resource.

Comment: The company in question is a small startup with 14 employees and very lacking security. I can see hashes for the userID and password after login in the page source.